# useRef React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I need to have a reference to a variable so that I can change the value of that variable both in `Canvas` and `ToolsMenu`. Therefore I made something similar to this...

```
function App() {
  const canvas = useRef(); // Value assigned in <Canvas />

  return (
    <>
      <Canvas canvas={canvas} />
      <ToolsMenu canvas={canvas} />
    </>
  );
}
```

But when I change the `canvas.current` value in `<ToolsMenu />`, the value in `<Canvas />` won't get updated.
Is there any way I can get something like a C++ pointer in React?

I don't think the `useState` hook would work because I change the value of `canvas` through methods (`canvas.getCommandStack().undo()`) and not through `setCanvas`

```
function App() {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(); // Assign in <Canvas />

  return (
    <>
      <Canvas canvas={canvas} setCanvas={setCanvas}/>
      <ToolsMenu canvas={canvas}/>
    </>
  );
}

function Canvas({ canvas, setCanvas }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setCanvas(new draw2d.Canvas("canvas"));
  }, []);

  // ...

  return <div id="canvas"></div>;
}

function ToolsMenu({ canvas }) {
  const undo = () => canvas?.getCommandStack().undo();
  const redo = () => canvas?.getCommandStack().redo();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={undo}>Undo</button>
      <button onClick={redo}>Redo</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Or would it still work?

Comment: @EmileBergeron I updated the question with more info.

Comment: Thank you, it makes way more sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself. It has nothing to do with the `useRef` hook.

I just forgot the `, []` in a `useEffect` hook, inside `<Canvas />`, that was initializing `canvas.current`. So I kept re-initializing the `canvas` after changing its value.

Comment: I was looking at the snippet in your question and found no obvious problem, so it wasn't an XY problem in the end. Happy you found out what it was!

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this?

```
function App() {
    const [ref, setRef] = usestate();

    return (
    <>
        <Comp1 value={ref} onChange={setRef(value)}/>
        <Comp2 value={ref} onChange={setRef(value)}/>
    </>
    );
}
```